# Filtrar dados de uma string com expressão regular

Tags: python, regex

Tenho uma variável que contém o nome completo da empresa e o CNPJ. Estou usando

```
verificaCnpj = re.search("\d{2}.\d{3}.\d{3}/\d{4}-\d{2}", variavel)
```

para localizar o CNPJ (pois há outras variáveis que NÃO CONTÉM CNPJ, e que deverão ser descartadas).

Quero SUBSTITUIR essa variável para que ela passe a conter APENAS o CNPJ, descartando o nome da empresa. Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta chamar o `group()`

```
cnpj = re.search("\d{2}.\d{3}.\d{3}/\d{4}-\d{2}", variavel).group()
```

Comment: Antes da chamada de `group` será necessário verificar se o texto possui o CNPJ, caso contrário a função `search` retornará `None`.